# Find number of touches supported by a device

Tags: android, touch, multi-touch

Is there any way to find out the number of touches a device supports.
Instead of manually touching and finding out the actual value, is there a way to programmatically find the value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are five possibilities:

1. The device does not have a touchscreen (`hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN)` returns `false`)
2. The device has a touchscreen but only supports single touch events (`hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN)` returns `true` but `hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH)` returns `false`)
3. The device has a touchscreen and supports multiple touches, but only really at the level of gestures (`hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH)` returns `true` but `hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_DISTINCT)` returns `false`)
4. The device has a touchscreen and supports two or more distinct touches but less than five (`hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_DISTINCT)` returns `true` but `hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_JAZZHAND)` returns `false`)
5. The device has a touchscreen and supports five or more distinct touches (`hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_JAZZHAND)` returns `true`)

You cannot find out any finer granularity than that.

BTW, the `hasSystemFeature()` method is found on `PackageManager`.